# Dynamically Create/Modify the xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

I am creating a XMl like this

```
                    var xml123:XML = <root></root>;
                    
                    xml123.appendChild(<node uri='${urlValues[0]}' ></node>);
                    
                    xml123.child("node").appendChild(<row></row>);
                    
                    xml123.child("node").child("row").appendChild(<item>item01</item>);
                    xml123.child("node").child("row").appendChild(<item>item02</item>);
                    
                    xml123.child("node").appendChild(<row></row>);
                    
                    xml123.child("node").row[1].appendChild(<item>item03</item>);
                    xml123.child("node").row[1].appendChild(<item>item04</item>);
```

Now i want to add a url value dynamically so i used this code `<node uri='${urlValues[0]}' ></node>` but its not working and i cant give `<node uri=${urlValues[0]} ></node>` is their any way so uri value can be take from a different variable ?
Value i am getting like this

```
var urlValues:Array ;
urlValues = userSelected.split("@");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable format is explained [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f95.html). So you don't need to construct XML with lots of code, you just need to mention variables in its body:

```
var X:XML =
<root>
  <FirstElement>
    First
  </FirstElement>
  <SecondElement SecondAtt={urlValues[0]}>
    Second
  </SecondElement>
</root>
```

If that doesn't work, you may assign the data to a local variable that SHOULD work:

```
var uv0:String = urlValues[0];
var X:XML =
<root>
  <FirstElement>
    First
  </FirstElement>
  <SecondElement SecondAtt={uv0}>
    Second
  </SecondElement>
</root>
```

Comment: Ok let me try this as well

Comment: Its Better Solution than what i added in question section.

Answer (score 0):

Ok at last i found how it can be achieve ,may be multiple solution but one solution which can do the work

```
var xml123 = new XML("<root></root>");
xml123.FirstElement = "First"; 
xml123.SecondElement = "Second"; 
xml123.SecondElement.@SecondAtt = urlValues[0];    // <- I know what value to input
```

So it will genrate the xml like this

```
<root>
  <FirstElement>
    First
  </FirstElement>
  <SecondElement SecondAtt="http://2.4.5.6:1000">
    Second
  </SecondElement>
</root>
```

So it will serve the purpose and i can easily add attribute dynamically. But issue with this method lots of code i have to write to generate the xml.